# How can I migrate monolithic MEAN stack application to Micro Services?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, microservices

We developed a monolithic MEAN stack application to manage Employees and Inventory in the office. How to use Employees as one service and Inventory as one service?

Answer (score 0):

Your application should be decomposed into smaller self sufficient units to utilize the full benefits of micro-service architecture.

So, you need to create 2 separate applications one for Employee management and another for Inventory management.

Before decomposing your application make sure you need this or not. As decomposing applications brings number of challenges which was not their in monolithic application like distributed routing between independent components, Centralized security mechanism, Inter-communication between different micro-services etc.